# How to autopopulate a google sheet task list into a dynamic google sheet calendar

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a google sheet with two tabs: task list and calendar. I am trying to auto-populate the task list (some have the same date) into the dynamic calendar in google sheets. Please help.

Here is the sample spreadsheet (I inserted mock data into the calendar tab to demonstrate the outcome) - I will approve access https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OBuaSuVFhaOdEjLEySU7xhHzAJlzweq9hNncA2YEBxA/edit#gid=486213619

I tried using this formula on each day in the calendar: =IFERROR(INDEX(Tasks!$B:$B,MATCH(Calendar!B4,Tasks!$A:$A,0),1),"") - formula references:

- Tasks!$B:$B = Task Date on Task tab
- Calendar!B4 = Corresponding Calendar Date on Calendar tab
- Tasks!$A:A = Task Name on Task tab

I expected the task from the task list to appear on the google sheet calendar for the corresponding day, but nothing is happening. Please help.

Comment: Your sheet is not accessible. Make it public.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way of importing format with a formula nor of stablishing partial format cells with special characters as yours for completed tasks.

But here I suggest a formula that lists the pending tasks firsts and then have a header that lists after it the completed ones:

```
=IFERROR(JOIN(CHAR(10),FILTER(Tasks!$A:$A,DAY(Tasks!$B:$B)=A4,MONTH(Tasks!$B:$B)=MONTH($A$1),YEAR(Tasks!$B:$B)=YEAR($A$1), Tasks!$C:$C=FALSE)))
&LAMBDA(comp,IF(comp<>"",CHAR(10)&"COMPLETED:"&CHAR(10)&comp,))     (IFERROR(JOIN(CHAR(10),FILTER(Tasks!$A:$A,DAY(Tasks!$B:$B)=A4,MONTH(Tasks!$B:$B)=MONTH($A$1),YEAR(Tasks!$B:$B)=YEAR($A$1), Tasks!$C:$C=TRUE))))
```

[image]

Let me know if that's useful!